# Conditional Rendering based on .count - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

I have a straightforward question, I've got an instance variable "@fam_act.count" which counts the number of activities performed by a family.

My code in the view reads

> Completed <%= @bal_act.count %> Activities

Currently if a family has completed just one activity, it reads, "Completed 1 Activities". I would like to add some conditional logic so that if Activities equals 1 it will display "Activity" instead of "Activities"

Something like: If @bal_act.count == 1 render "Activity" else "Activities"

What is the correct syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pluralize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize)

```
Completed <%= pluralize(@bal_act.count, 'Activity', 'Activities') %>
```

Comment: Works. Thanks so much, I knew there had to be a cool Ruby method for that.

- Thx HungryCoder